# How do I ensure that a CSS file that's loaded during a partial-postback from an UpdatePanel is applied before JavaScript is executed?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I'm developing a custom control in ASP.NET 3.5 that uses embedded CSS and JavaScript resources. The control works great normally but when it's placed inside an UpdatePanel, there is a timing issue where some JavaScript is executed before the embedded CSS file is loaded and applied. The JavaScript depends on properties in the CSS to function correctly. I can get everything I need to appear in the `<head>` tag correctly, but I can't solve the timing issue unless I render a `<style>` element inside the UpdatePanel and dump the contents of the CSS file into it, forcing it to load in a timely manner. Here's a basic idea of what I was trying before resorting to that. Since you can't just add the CSS link to the header controls collection on the server side when using AJAX, the preferred method seems to be to register a script to insert it in the head back on the client side. In the `<head>` tag I would end up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=yvr2-IBhAQRL9mkn-eB25Q2&amp;t=633962690150696688"></script><!-- Custom control functions -->
<script type="text/javascript">//one-line script that inserts CSS link in head</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebResource.axd?d=AP8xhKnwsJ9gvRD_ilG0I8ZV2eFcjUevPkzvdMOyuEJttsxE300BabUFg8bCLsiP0&amp;t=634404581860000000" /><!-- the CSS that got loaded by the line above -->
<script type="text/javascript">//one-line script to call a setup function that depends on the CSS file above being loaded and applied already, which it is not</script>
```

I know it's a timing issue because if I step through it in firebug or use an alert or anything else to delay execution of the JavaScript, then it works fine. I'm not really interested in using a library like LazyLoad to do this. It seems to me that if I have to use such a library to do something as simple as load a CSS file, then I'm doing something wrong. I'm also not interested in non-UpdatePanel solutions. I'm married to that for now and I'm just wondering if there's a reliable way to do it with the tools I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript part of the UpdatePanel to synchronize, or load with the order you like the css and execute the javascript.

Here is the code that fire on the javascript side before and after the update

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      

}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
   // here the update panel finish the loading, so next load the css, 
   //  then execute your javascript
}
```

Comment: By load the css, you mean dynamically insert a `<link>` element in the `<head>` right? I've tried doing this with the PageRequestManager and the CSS does appear in the head before the script that relies on it, but it doesn't seem to actually get applied in time, and a certain element's outerWidth property is not set correctly. It seems that inserting the `<link>` element in the `<head>` is not the same as actually loading/applying the CSS. That seems to happen later.